# Want to get full url by php but not want to get ajax calling script page

Tags: php, ajax, session

I make my a session variable to save my last page. If user login/logout, its returned him to same page. its working well. But now I make ajax call every 5 second interval for new comment notification by notify.php page. So if I login/logout, now my script return me to notify.php page. I can't avoid ajax call for some reason.

So, Have any way to avoid all background script page to set as session variable ?

Here is my code for session variable:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['url'])){
     $this->refer = $_SESSION['url'];
  }else{
     $this->refer = "/";
  }

/* Set current url */
  $this->url = $_SESSION['url'] = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: `if (url != 'notify.php')`?

Comment: just make an exception for `notify.php`, and prohibit it to access `$_SESSION['url']`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header value. If it's  `xmlhttprequest` then it's an AJAX request.

So your code would look like this,

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
       // It's an AJAX call.
}
else {
      // Save last visited URL here..
}
```

> Although these values can easily be changed, as they come from client side and we cannot trust that data.

---

If you just have single or couple of `URL` which is used for `AJAX`, you can directly compare the URL with them to filter out the AJAX call, this would be good in compare to above solution.